# SharePoint Online JSON List Formatting

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

So I have a column with the internal name of `usersubmitter`. When I use this column in my JSON it appears as [object Object]. However if I try and pull the .title value of this object nothing renders at all - this column is definitely populated with a user. Does anyone know why this isn't working?

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/row-formatting.schema.json",
  "hideColumnHeader": true,
  "hideSelection": true,
  "groupProps": {
    "headerFormatter": {
      "elmType": "div",
      "txtContent": "@group.fieldData",
      "style": {
        "font-size": "24px",
        "width": "100%",
        "padding": "3px",
        "font-weight": "4px",
        "color": "black",
        "border-style": "solid",
        "border-width": "2px",
        "border-color": "black"
      }
    }
  },
  "rowFormatter": {
    "elmType": "div",
    "style": {
      "display": "flex",
      "flex-direction": "column",
      "align-items": "flex-start"
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "children": [
          {
            "elmType": "span",
            "txtContent": "[$InformationContent]"
          },
          {
            "elmType": "span",
            "txtContent": " - Submitted by"
          },
          {
            "elmType": "span",
            "txtContent": "[$usersubmitter.title]"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "attributes": {
          "class": "ms-borderColor-themeDark"
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "elmType": "span",
            "txtContent": "\n"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Just want to confirm, what is the column/data type, person or group? single selection or multiple selection column?

Comment: I just tried the same JSON in my SharePoint list with single selection person or group column and it is showing name of user correctly.

Comment: Yeah it's a person or group collumn - it renders as blank with the code I have in place :/

Comment: Did you enable multiple selections for this column or it is a single selection only?

Comment: @GaneshSanap It's a single selection only collumn

Comment: Strange! can you show us the screenshot of sample list view (with grouping and user column)? Also, double check if you are using correct internal name of column in JSON.

Comment: Yeah so this is my list item, https://prnt.sc/UdWYaBkPbo9N. And here's my view with the formatting https://prnt.sc/g3j0VRIx4rbn - if I use just usersubmitter without the .title it appears as object object so I'm adamant I'm accessing the right variable but here's a screenshot of the collumn edit link aswell; https://prnt.sc/SYX70pluMqOW

Comment: @GaneshSanap and this is the edit window for the item; https://prnt.sc/h_EyMQjwDpIG

Comment: With these settings and JSON, it should have worked for you. Can you try creating a new list with similar columns and test there to see if you can reproduce this issue in another list?

Comment: @GaneshSanap I'll give it a try and get back to you thanks for the help :)

Comment: @GaneshSanap It works on a seperate list with the same setup :(

Comment: Is this list/application live in productions? If not, you can re-create list if needed. Meanwhile try raising support ticket with Microsoft directly: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/get-help-support?view=o365-worldwide#online-support